# Python Selenium Javascript Login

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to login into this website whit selenium and Python:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/login?targetUrl=~2FWebObjects~2FiTunesConnect.woa~2Fra~2Fng~2Fapp~2F719525810~2Faddons

Unfortunately, the code source doesn't show the Id=apple_Id that I need to send my login information but when I inspect the page I see it.

So Page Source looks something like this:
[image: PageSource]

Bu what i need is in the inspect window:
[image: InspectWindow]

I think its because its javascript rendered or something but I can't figure how to do it!

thanks

Comment: Hey there! Can you please include a [mcve] _in your question_?

Comment: I have added it in picture because of the length of the HTML

Comment: This isn't particularly _minimal_...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required `input` field located inside an `iframe`, so to be able to handle it you should switch to `iframe` first:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "aid-auth-widget-iFrame")))
driver.find_element_by_id("appleId").send_keys('text')
```

Comment: Thanks it works great ! Could you tell me how can I know it's and iframe ?

Comment: You mean you want to know how to define whether element located in `iframe`?

Comment: Yes, I wanna know how did you know it was an "aid-auth-widget-iFrame"

Comment: You can check ancestors of `input` in page source. There is an element `<iframe>`. It's on your second screenshot

Comment: And what if there is not ifram division but the source code doesnt contain what I can find in the inspect menu ?

Comment: Then it means that required element generated dynamically, so you should wait until it present in `DOM`: `wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "appleId")))`